How to disable binary logs in RDS using MariaDB?
I am using MariaDB 10.11 on Amazon RDS and want to disable binary logs.
I created a custom parameter group but can't find the appropriate option. It seems that MySQL binary logs can be disabled using binlog_retention_hours but I can't find an equivalent option for MariaDB.
